# Prompt: Date, %Sysfunc(year(&myvar.));

Tags: date, variables, macros, sas, prompt

I have a SAS EG 7.1 program that generates reports on a monthly basis. The old process was very manual, where users, amongst other things, were asked to update a macro variable (&date.) with current month-end (Date9.).

```
    %let Date = '28feb2018'd; /* <--- Input the date to be reported  */

    /* Generate the year and the month based on the input date */
    %let year = %sysfunc(year(&date.)); 
    %let month = %sysfunc(month(&date.));
```

The &year (4-digit) and &month. (1- or 2-digit depending on the month) are later used in the code as components of a filename to pick up current month's tables:

```
    FROM lib.great_table_loc_&year._&month.;
```

I am trying to make the program dynamic by prompting the user to chose the current month-end date. 
The prompt is working, and outputs date9. format.

I then tried using the macro variable &Prompt_date. in the %sysfunc:

```
    %let Date = '&prompt_date.'; 
    %let year = %sysfunc(year(&prompt_date.)); 
    %let month = %sysfunc(month(&prompt_date.));
```

When I execute, I get the following error messages:

1)

```
    35         %let year = %sysfunc(year(&prompt_date.));
    ERROR: Argument 1 to function YEAR referenced by the %SYSFUNC or 
    %QSYSFUNC macro function is not a number.
    ERROR: Invalid arguments detected in %SYSCALL, %SYSFUNC, or %QSYSFUNC 
    argument list.  Execution of %SYSCALL statement or %SYSFUNC 
           or %QSYSFUNC function reference is terminated.
    36         %let month = %sysfunc(month(&prompt_date.));
    ERROR: Argument 1 to function MONTH referenced by the %SYSFUNC or 
    %QSYSFUNC macro function is not a number.
    ERROR: Invalid arguments detected in %SYSCALL, %SYSFUNC, or %QSYSFUNC 
    argument list.  Execution of %SYSCALL statement or %SYSFUNC 
           or %QSYSFUNC function reference is terminated.
```

2)

```
    118         lib.great_table_loc_._.
                                    _
                                    22
                                    200
    ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: a name, ;, 
    (, ',', ANSIMISS, AS, CROSS, EXCEPT, FULL, GROUP, HAVING, 
          INNER, INTERSECT, JOIN, LEFT, NATURAL, NOMISS, ORDER, OUTER, 
    RIGHT, UNION, WHERE.  

    ERROR 200-322: The symbol is not recognized and will be ignored.
```

I've tried creating a separate field for month and year, formatted to YYMMN6., input the &prompt_date. and then put(,n.) to make the value numeric - still nothing.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem? 
Any tips on how to get what I want?

Thanks!

Comment: When you created the prompt, what Prompt Type did you select? you may have selected date,date-range or timestamp. and what method did you select for populating?

Comment: What value did PROMPT_DATE actually have in it?  Add `%put &prompt_date. ;` to your program to have SAS write it to the log.

Comment: Hi! It outputs this:
        26         %put &prompt_date.;
        31Mar2018

Which is the same format as the previous manual input (i.e. 28feb2018). 
The prompt value is Date, and the prompt specifies a value must be input. They chose from a 'calendar' popup at the prompt.

Comment: So it is not a valid date value. But it can be converted to a date literal (like in the hard coded example) by adding quotes and the trailing letter d.  `"&prompt_date"d`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have:

```
%let Date = '&prompt_date.'; 
%let year = %sysfunc(year(&prompt_date.)); 
%let month = %sysfunc(month(&prompt_date.));
```

Two issues.

1. you assign &Date but don't use it.
2. prompt date is DDMONYYYY (date9.).  SAS will see that as a string.  You need quotes and a `d` to make it a date.

Try

```
%let year = %sysfunc(year("&prompt_date."d)); 
%let month = %sysfunc(month("&prompt_date."d));
```

Comment: Running now, seems to be working! Will let you know, thanks!

Comment: Hi again! It worked! Thank you! 
RE: Date, it is used as input for a field (datadate) in the report table. Thank you again!!

Comment: Great!  If it solves your problem, please accept the answer.

Comment: Done Mr. Man! :)

Comment: If you want month to have a leading zero for Jan to Sep then use the Z format to generate the macro variable. `%let month = %sysfunc(month("&prompt_date."d),Z2);`